# Plus Signs converted to spaces in Google Apps Script + MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql

I was using Google Apps as a REST API for a web application, but discovered that the API would not preserve plus signs whenever I attempted to insert a new record. Because of the same origin policy on browsers, the JSON had to be passed on to the API as a parameter on the URL. The process first strigifyied the JSON and then escaped the value using the escape function in JavaScript.

However, once the request reaches Google Apps, the Google process that parses the request object before reaching doGet() treats the unescaped "+" as a space.

This is a really maddening kind of bug to identify, so if anybody else comes across it, I hope my experience fixing it helps. Just use encodeURIComponent() instead of escape() and that should do the trick.

Comment: Look into prepared statements. No escaping needed.

Comment: @David I already did, but there is no avoiding having to escape certain characters anyway because the statement may contain a string that requires some escaping. Plus, using prepared statements adds a lot of complexity to my sql builder. I would rather handle the escaping with JavaScript, but I need to know ALL the characters that need escaping. Obviously, somebody at Oracle dropped the ball on writing comprehensive enough documentation on that matter because "surprise!" a literal plus sign is not listed in the documentation as a character to escape. I don't want any more surprises like that.

Comment: "a literal plus sign is not listed in the documentation as a character to escape" --- that's because *surprise* `+` is not special in any kind for SQL in general and its mysql dialect in particular. For your task you don't need to take care of at least half of escape sequences you enumerated.

Comment: "The table above makes no mention of a "+" plus sign needing to be escaped, but if it is not, then it converts into a space" --- it does not. If it does - it's converted by something else, not by mysql.

Comment: Are you saying that you're writing a low-level adapter for talking to MySQL...?! I somehow doubt that. What is actually connecting to the database in the end? In some form or another, you should be involving the MySQL client libraries at some point, which contain all the escaping functions necessary.

Comment: All of you raise good points. Actually, I had not considered whether or not the adapter (JDBC Class in Google Apps Script), might be the culprit.https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fapps-script%2Freference%2Fjdbc%2Fjdbc&ei=nHmrVPijOYmgyQTelYGABQ&usg=AFQjCNE1XpIcVyj97aRfH-T7UQkdcIjTMw&bvm=bv.82001339,d.aWw

Comment: @deceze I have already written an adapter for talking with MySql. It is quite robust already. I just need some help figuring out why it's converting my plus signs into spaces. I have a sneaking suspicion it actually is the JDBC adapter (the Google component). I will have to run a test using a different one in a different language to know for sure.

Comment: Plus-to-space sounds very much like URL encoding/decoding behaves. Are you sure you're not tunnelling your data through HTTP somewhere with the receiving end URL-decoding `+` to space?

Comment: Also, what I'm trying to say is, why are you looking to do this in Javascript? Javascript is not actually the technology that connects to the database, is it? Are you preparing an SQL string in Javascript and then send it on to a Java/JDBC process which just takes that SQL query and executes it? That sounds pretty bad. I hope I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @deceze Google Apps Script does communicate with a back-end that is built upon Java. However, Google Apps Script itself is pure JavaScript, and yes! You can connect it directly to a database! Far from being "bad", it is actually quite elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a red herring!

So this is what happened. I have a URL that contains the request to the API to insert a record with a value that contains a plus. Client-side, I was using the escape function to do this, but the escape function did not encode the plus sign. When the request comes through server-side, however, apparently whatever component there is on the back end of Google Apps that parses the URL parameters then treats the plus sign as a space. It was hard to identify because within the Google Apps script itself, using unescape successfully decodes the parameter, thereby making it appear that MySQL was the problem.

The solution? I switched to using encodeURIComponent instead of escape, and now it works!

Answer (score 3):

None of them.

Use prepared statements. They remove any kind of need for concern about what you're passing as a parameter. That's why they exist.

Comment: Thank you, but I truly think there has to be a better way to go about this than to completely revise my project for one little plus sign. KISS. I can always revise the input in some way that the application layer can handle it.

Comment: Erm... plus signs are harmless anyway... and it's hard to get any simpler than prepared statements.

Comment: It's just a matter of how the custom controller I wrote works. Redesigning it to handle prepared statements is a lot of work for little gain.